# ASP.NET Dynamically created controls in C#: failed events

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls

I am creating a web application that requires controls to be created dynamically on the click of a button, and then add the controls to an already constructed asp:table.

The problem is that the events for the dynamic controls do not fire (ciDD_SelectedIndexChanged).

In order: the button is clicked, it sets a Session variable for the control IDs, creates the controls, then adds them to the table row. This is done OnClick, and OnInit for post back.

Is there an easy way to set the event for the dynamic controls, or am I going about this in a horrible way?

The button and it's event:

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="addHardware" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/plus.png" Height="24" Width="24" OnClick="addHardware_Click" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" style="margin-left:7px" Visible="false" />

    protected void addHardware_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["rowCount"] = (Convert.ToInt32(Session["rowCount"]) + 1); 
        CreateControls(Convert.ToInt32(Session["rowCount"]));
        CreateRow(Convert.ToInt32(Session["rowCount"]));
    }
```

The Control creation function and the list they are saved to:

```
    private static List<Control> _controls = new List<Control>();
    private static List<Control> HWControls
    {
        get { return _controls; }
    }

    protected void CreateControls(int i)
    {
        DropDownList ci = new DropDownList();
        ci.AutoPostBack = true;
        ci.ID = "ciDD" + i;
        ci.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.ciDD_SelectedIndexChanged);
        ci.Items.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
        ci.Items.Add(new ListItem("test1", "test1"));
        ci.Items.Add(new ListItem("test2", "test2"));

        DropDownList dt = new DropDownList();
        dt.ID = "deviceTypeDD" + i;
        DropDownList m = new DropDownList();
        m.ID = "modelDD" + i;
        TextBox qt = new TextBox();
        qt.ID = "qtTB" + i;
        DropDownList dv = new DropDownList();
        dv.ID = "deviceNumDD" + i;
        TextBox sn = new TextBox();
        sn.ID = "serialTB" + i;

        HWControls.Add(ci);
        HWControls.Add(dt);
        HWControls.Add(m);
        HWControls.Add(qt);
        HWControls.Add(dv);
        HWControls.Add(sn);
    }
```

The Row creation function, and it's corresponding List:

```
    private static List<TableRow> _rows = new List<TableRow>();
    private static List<TableRow> Rows
    {
        get { return _rows; }
    }

    protected void CreateRow(int i)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();

        cell.Controls.Add(HWControls.Find(x => x.ID.Contains("ciDD" + i)));
        cell1.Controls.Add(HWControls.Find(x => x.ID.Contains("deviceTypeDD" + i)));
        cell2.Controls.Add(HWControls.Find(x => x.ID.Contains("modelDD" + i)));
        cell3.Controls.Add(HWControls.Find(x => x.ID.Contains("qtTB" + i)));
        cell4.Controls.Add(HWControls.Find(x => x.ID.Contains("deviceNumDD" + i)));
        cell5.Controls.Add(HWControls.Find(x => x.ID.Contains("serialTB" + i)));

        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        row.Cells.Add(cell3);
        row.Cells.Add(cell4);
        row.Cells.Add(cell5);

        Rows.Add(row);

        hardwareTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

The OnInit to recreate the controls/rows after post back:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["rowCount"]);
        if (i != 0)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                CreateControls(j);
                CreateRow(j);
            }
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating the eventhandlers in the PreInit phase solved the issue.

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in HWControls)
        {
            if(c.ID.Contains("ciDD"))
            {
                ((DropDownList)c).SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.ciDD_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
            else if (c.ID.Contains("deviceTypeDD"))
            {
                ((DropDownList)c).SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.deviceTypeDD_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
    }
```